# Hoffman and Kunze, linear algebra chapter 1 exercise

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, systems-of-equations

Suppose $R_1$ and $R_2$ are $2\times 3$ row-reduced echelon matrices and that the systems $R_1X=0$ and $R_2X=0$ have the same solutions. Prove that $R_1=R_2$

I wrote down the $5$ different types of row reduced echelon $2\times 3$ matrices but it got me nowhere. It was tedious.

I tried contradiction; suppose $R_1\ne R_2,$ then there exists $i,j$ such that $ 1\le i\le 2,1\le j\le 3$ and $R_{1_{ij}}\ne R_{2_{ij}}.$ But I am not able to make use of this information to lead to a contradiction.

EDIT: I think I might be able to use this lemma :

[If two homogeneous systems of linear equations have the same solutions, then they are equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1979314/two-homogenous-system-are-equivalent-if-they-have-the-same-answer/2263778#2263778)

Coming back to the solution - So now, I can conclude that since $R_1$ and $R_2$ are row-equivalent and they must be the same since row-reduced echelon matrices are unique.

Please help me verify.

Comment: Hint: $(R_1-R_2)X=0$

Comment: @Itay4 could you help me more?

Comment: Let $R_1-R_2=B.$ Suppose $B$ is non-zero, so that $B$ can at the most be row-equivalent to one of them. Would this lead me anywhere?

Comment: If I show $B$ is row equivalent to both, I'm done