# Relationship between Row Space and Reduced Row Echelon Form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Consider two matrices **A** and **B** having the same dimension. It is said that: if **A** and **B** have different reduced row echelon forms (RREFs), then their row spaces are different.

Any one know how to prove this statement? Or, is there any reference (book) on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832109/exact-same-solutions-implies-same-row-reduced-echelon-form) seems related, but it just says "In the row reduced echelon form the nonzero rows form a basis for the row space of the original matrix, and hence two matrices with the same row space will have the same row reduced echelon form." However, this does not take care of the concern that two different bases for the same row space could lead to different RREFs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is easier to prove the contrapositive instead: If two matrices have the same row space, then they have the same RREF.

Assume $A$ and $B$ have the same row space. Also, let's say they are both $n \times m$ matrices. This means for any $x \in \Bbb{R}^n$, there is a $y \in \Bbb{R}^n$ such that $x^tA=y^tB$.

Now, let $e_i \in \Bbb{R}^n$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$ be the sandard basis of $\Bbb{R}^n$ and let $y_i \in \Bbb{R}^n$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$ satisfy the equation $e_i^tA=y_i^tB$. Now, make a matrix such that the $i^{\text{th}}$ row of the matrix is $y_i^t$. Call this matrix $R$.

Note that there might be multiple possible $y_i$ for some $e_i$. We want $R$ to be nonsingular, so we need to choose these rows so they are linearly independent. If the rank of matrix $A$ is $k$, then there are $k$ rows of $A$ that are linearly independent. We will call these rows $e_{l_i}^tA$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$. We will call the other rows $e_{m_i}^tA$ for $1 \leq i \leq n-k$.

- For the rows with index $l_i$, find a solution $y_{l_i}$ and then write $y_{l_i}^t=u_{l_i}^t+v_{l_i}^t$ where the $u^t$s are in the left null space of $B$ and the $v^t$s are in the orthogonal complement of the left null space of $B$. Then, choose $v_{l_i}^t$ as the row for $R$. Since all of the $e_{l_i}^tA$ are linearly independent and $e_{l_i}^tA=v_{l_i}^tB$, all of the $v_{l_i}^tB$ are linearly independent, so all of the $v_{l_i}^t$ are linearly independent.
- For the rows with index $m_i$, find a solution $y_{m_i}$ and then write $y_{m_i}^t=u_{m_i}^t+v_{m_i}^t$ where the $u^t$s are in the left null space of $B$ and the $v^t$s are in the orthogonal complement of the left null space of $B$. Then, write a basis for the left null space of $B$. The row space of $B$ is equal to the row space of $A$, which has dimensionality $k$. Thus, by the Fundamental Theorem of Linear Algebra, the left null space has dimensionality $n-k$. Therefore, we can write a basis for the left null space of $B$ as $n_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n-k$. Now, we will choose $v_{m_i}^t+n_i^t$ as the row for $R$. These are linearly independent from all of the $v_{l_i}^t$ since those were all in the orthogonal complement of the left null space and thus can not span $n_i^t$. Also, they are all independent from each other because they all have a different $n_i^t$, which are linearly independent from each other since they are a basis.

Clearly, we have $e_i^tR=y_i^t$, so we have $e_i^tRB=y_i^tB$, so by Transitive Property, we get $e_i^tRB=e_i^tA$. Now, $e_i^tM$ for any matrix $M$ represents the $i^{\text{th}}$ row of $M$. This means the $e_i^tRB=e_i^tA$ is the same as saying the $i^{\text{th}}$ row of $RB$ is equal to the $i^{\text{th}}$ row of $A$. Thus, since all of their rows are equal, we have $A=RB$. Since $R$ is nonsingular, this means $A$ is row equivalent to $B$, so $A$ and $B$ have the same RREF.

Comment: Thanks Noble. I can accept that "_A_ and _B_ have the same row space if and only if _A_ is row equivalent to _B_". In fact, this is stated in many textbooks. However, can you explain more on "if _A_ is row equivalent to _B_, then _A_ and _B_ should have the same RREF"?

Comment: @GaryTam It is obvious that $B$ is row equivalent to $\text{rref}(B)$. If $A$ is row equivalent to $B$, then by Transitive Property, $A$ is row equivalent to $\text{rref}(B)$. Since $A$ can only be row equivalent to one RREF since every matrix has a unique RREF, this means that the $\text{rref}(A)=\text{rref}(B)$, so $A$ and $B$ have the same RREF.

Comment: Some minor gap-filling: $$\sum_i \lambda_i v_{l_i}^t =0 \implies 0 = \sum_i \lambda_i v_{l_i}^t B = \sum_i \lambda_i e_{l_i}^t A$$  , and since the $e_{l_i}^t A$ are linearly independent, all $\lambda_i$ must be zero. 
 Sorry if you got a notification from me trying to comment twice, I tried inserting a line break in Android and it didn't work.

Comment: Great answer ..

Answer (score 0):

The row space of a matrix is the same as its row echelon form since you are performing elementary row operations. In RREF certain properties must be satisfied:

- The first non-zero entry of the row is $1$ (this is the pivot of the row)
- Every element below the pivot is a $0$.
- Each row that contains a leading 1 has zeros everywhere else.
- All rows of $0$ are in the bottom of the matrix.

Then if A and B have different RREF, then their row space are different too. Why? Let's put an example:

$M= \begin{bmatrix} -1&3&2 \\ -2&5&3 \\ -3&1&-2 \end{bmatrix}$

As you can notice $C_3 = C_1 + C_2$ then $rank(M) = 2$ and if you attempt to put in RREF is:

$\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&1 \\ 0&1&1 \\ 0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$ but it doesn't satisfy the rule $3$.

If we work with a new matrix $M'$ with $rank(M')=3$ and we attempt to put in RREF then we will end up with:

$M'= \begin{bmatrix} -1&3&5 \\ -2&5&-7 \\ -3&1&11 \end{bmatrix}$

In RREF form : $\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0 \\ 0&1&0 \\ 0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$

Thus both matrices $M$ and $M'$ have different row spaces and ranks.

Comment: Well, in fact the matrix **A** itself can have many different row echelon forms, but certainly these row echelon forms have the same row space. What I mean is reduced row echelon forms (RREFs), which seems _unique_ for matrix **A**. E.g. see [link] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) .
Can you be more specific / rigorous?

Comment: @GaryTam matrix A can have many different refs since you can add a scalar multiply of a row to other row. But RREF satisfy certain conditions that I am going to add to my post.

Comment: Seems the question reduces to: is the RREF of a matrix unique?

Comment: @GaryTam Yes, as a consequence of the rules defined in my post. I've seen in the past alternative proofs that try to prove the uniqueness of RREF.

Comment: @kub0x I do not think this problem is just "is the RREF unique?" You have to prove that matrices with two different RREFs have different row spaces, and two matrices with different RREFs can have the same rank, so this isn't just a thing that follows trivially from the uniqueness of RREFs.

Comment: The phrase "The row space of a matrix is the same as its row echelon form" is nonsensical. The _row space_ is a subspace of a vector space; the _row echelon form_ is a matrix. They are so different types of objects, that claiming that they are the same thing makes no sense. Of course, there's a certain relation between them, but that's a different story. In fact, that's what the OP's question is, in a way: to explain this relation.

Comment: And another note: an example is not a proof. Examples are great, and math would be vacuous without them, but the OP specifically asked for a proof.

Comment: I'm sorry that I can make confusion in some topics but I'm afraid I'm not fully able to explain the whole issue perfectly, that's why I include some examples. Two matrices with different RREF can have same rank, I agree in that (that's elemental) by the way I would redirect you to http://www.cs.uleth.ca/~holzmann/notes/reduceduniq.pdf

Comment: @kub0x Uniqueness of RREF does not solve this problem, though. Even if every matrix has a unique RREF, it is still possible that two different non-row equivalent matrices have the same row space and it is still possible that two different bases of the same row space lead to different RREFs.